# Cannot modify association 'Survey#answers' because it goes through more than one other association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested

I have a nested form that handles a survey and its answers. But I'm getting a strange error when I load the form:

ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughNestedAssociationsAreReadonly

Any ideas? I'm not sure how I should be fixing the associations.

```
<%= form_for @survey do |f| %>

...
<%= f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>
  <%= builder.text_field :content, :class=>"form-control" %>
<% end %>

...

<% end %>
```

Survey#new

```
  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
    @template = Template.find(params[:template_id])
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    @survey.answers.build
  end
```

Survey.rb

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :template
      has_many :questions, :through=> :template
      has_many :answers, :through=> :questions
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
    end
```

Template.rb

```
class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :survey
    has_many :questions
end
```

Question.rb

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :template
  has_many :answers
end
```

Answer.rb

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

Comment: hi! I'm running into a similar problem, did you ever find a working solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

You've missed the line `has_many :templates` in the Survey.rb.
Also you must specify `:templates` (plural of the model name) in the
same file:

`has_many :questions, :through=> :templates`

So final variant is:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :templates
      has_many :questions, :through=> :templates
      has_many :answers, :through=> :questions
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :answers
    end
```

Also as your models `survey` and `answer` are associated, you don't need to get templates in controller:

```
def new
    @survey = Survey.new
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    @survey.answers.build
end
```

Comment: Hmmm... That's still not solving the error unfortunately.